# Setting anonymous interface in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, lambda, kotlin, adapter

I have an interface in my `Adapter` class:

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(view: View)
}
```

TAKE NOTE that my `interface` is in Kotlin.

which I want to set via this method:

```
public fun setItemClickListener(itemClickListener: OnItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = itemClickListener
}
```

How do I use the `setItemClickListener` method in my `Fragment` class like what I used to do in Java? i.e.

```
adapter.setItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(View view) {
    // do something
   }
}
```

I know that I can use an `onItemTouchListener` but I am still new to Kotlin and I'm trying to learn some techniques like `Lambdas` and such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your interface is defined in Kotlin (since it has `fun`). [Lambdas can only be used for Java interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions):

> Also note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported.

So in Kotlin you are supposed to use

```
public fun setItemClickListener(itemClickListener: (View) -> Unit)
```

instead of defining `OnItemClickListener`. You could also create a factory method:

```
// in Adapter's companion object
public inline fun OnItemClickListener(body: (View) -> Unit) = object : OnItemClickListener {
    override fun onItemClick(view: View) { body(view) }
}
```

and then

```
adapter.setItemClickListener(Adapter.OnItemClickListener { view -> ... })
```

Comment: This cleared things out for me. Thank you. However, how can I use the `OnItemClickListener` inline factory method?

Comment: Edited to show use.

Comment: sorry, but how do I call the `onItemClick` inside my adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method?

Comment: Do you understand how to access the listener? Then call the method on it as normal.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just new to Kotlin. Can you give me a code snipper? @Alexey Romanov

Comment: `adapter.getItemClickListener().onItemClick(someView)`

Answer (score 7):

Without lambda you can do it like this

```
adapter.setItemClickListener(object :View.OnItemClickListener{
            override fun onItemClick(p0: View?) {

            }
        })
```

Comment: so far this is the only answer that worked for me. But I really want to learn more about lambdas.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to assign interface with single method, you can just write this:

```
adapter.setItemClickListener { view ->
    /* some code here */
}
```

Or even better:

```
adapter.setItemClickListener { 
    /* some code here, to use "view" use keyword "it" */
}
```

If you want look deeper, let's analize signature of your method:

```
public fun setItemClickListener(itemClickListener: OnItemClickListener)
```

this is actually equals to

```
public fun setItemClickListener(singleMethodListener: (View) -> Unit)
```

If your last argument is function, you can just forget about '()', and pass lambda.
One more example:

```
public fun setItemClickListener(parameter: Int, singleMethodListener: (View) -> Unit)
```

to call method above, your code should be:

```
item.setItemClickListener(0) { /* lambda here */ }
```

The problem is when you have interface with more than one method, because then you cannot pass lambda :(

Example:

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
     fun onItemClick(view: View)
     fun onDoubleItemClick(view: View)
}
```

Then, you cannot pass sample labda, because you have to define 2 methods. Then, you have to do the same thing like in java, but in other syntax:

```
adapter.setItemClickListener(object : OnItemClickListener {
    /* method declarations here, like in java */
})
```

I hope I have explained base-lambda syntax in Kotlin :D Any question? Ask ;)

Comment: I have tried the first and second solution but it doesn't work. It says `Required: Adapter. OnItemClickListener Found: () -> Unit`

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do it in lambda

```
adapter.setItemClickListener{ Log.i("Adapter", "onItemClick event fired on " + it.id) }
```

Here `it` is the instance of `View` which is the parameter of `onItemClick` method.

More information on `it` is here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter

You can find more information in Kotlin docs here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions

Comment: Hi, your code doesn't seem to compile. Says `Type mismatch Required UpdatesAdapter.OnItemClickListener Found: () -> Int)`

Comment: Does your `UpdatesAdapter.OnItemClickListener` have only one method?

Comment: @Cililing yes. It is `fun onItemClick(view: View)`