# creating a custom argument matcher confusing implementation

Tags: java, mockito

I have seen someone creating a custom argument matcher like the following. However, I am having difficulty understanding how it works.

What I can understand its a method that takes a parameter and returns a ArgumentMatcher which is an interface that has a type of `List<Person>`. And the overriden method is the matcher that uses a lambda. I think the body part is the most confusing, if anyone can explain that.

```
private ArgumentMatcher<List<Person> personListSize(final int size) {
        return argument -> argument.personList().size() == size;
}
```

This is the way I would normally do something like this, which to me is easier to understand, just wondering how can I get the following to look like the above?

```
public class CustomArgumentMatcher implements ArgumentMatcher<List<Person>> {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(List<Person> argument) {
        return argument.size() == size;
    }
}
```

Just starting to understand, this works:

```
 private ArgumentMatcher<String> stringMatcher = new ArgumentMatcher<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(String argument) {
            return argument.contains("");
        }
    };
```

However, If I add a parameter to pass in like this:

```
 private ArgumentMatcher<String> stringMatcherArgs(final String name) = new ArgumentMatcher<String>() {
}
```

I get a error message saying `unexpected token` just wondering to pass in a parameter in the above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the arrow operator, '->', do in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146052/what-does-the-arrow-operator-do-in-java)

Comment: Do you want to convert your CustomArgumentMatcher class that checks `argument.size() == size` to a method like the personListSize method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read this document about [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Here are your examples:

```
private ArgumentMatcher<List<Person>> customArgumentMatcher(final int size) {
    return argument -> argument.size() == size;
}
```

```
private ArgumentMatcher<List<Person>> stringMatcherArgs(final String name) {
    return argument -> argument.contains(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am confused about one thing. `stringMatcherArgs` is a method declaration that has a ArgumentMatcher<T> return type. However, in the body a boolean is being returned.

Comment: Because the body is implementing the body of the method `matches` of the ArgumentMatcher class, which returns a Boolean `public boolean matches(String argument)`

Comment: because method declaration is implementing the body of the ArgumentMatcher interface `matches(T argument)` which it does using the lambda expression `argument -> agrument.contains(name)` So the return type with be the return type of the method in the interface. Just for a clearer undestanding do you have any examples of this?

Comment: Sorry I'm a little bit confused by your request. Isn't the examples in my answer?

Comment: Just wondering what I wrote in my last comment was correct declaring the return type to be a Interface in a method and implementing and return in the body

Comment: I was just trying to implement the same matcher using kotlin: `private fun customArgumentMatcher(size: Int): ArgumentMatcher<List<Person>> {
        return { argument -> argument.size == size }
    }` And in this snippet the compile error would be that its expecting the argument matcher and not the boolean. Can this not be done the same way in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

You got it all correct just connect the dots...

```
private ArgumentMatcher<List<Person> personListSize(final int size) {
  return new ArgumentMatcher<List<Person>>() {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(List<Person> argument) {
        return argument.size() == size;
    }
  };
}
```

and use it with `argThat`

```
Mockito.verify(mockClass).foo(argThat(personListSize(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your still looking for the kotlin equivalent of Gustavo`s answer
(note that you should have created another question instead),

try the following:

```
fun customArgumentMatcher(size : Int) :  ArgumentMatcher<List<Person>> {
    return object : ArgumentMatcher<List<Person>> {
        override fun matches(argument : List<Person>) = argument.size == size;
    }
}
```

See also:
[Setting anonymous interface in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50921677/setting-anonymous-interface-in-kotlin)